# ssh tunnel in putty for an ssh connection

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking, putty

I have configured a putty session to login into a server (server A) and make an ssh connection to another server (server B) automatically by adding a remote command in putty (ssh server B) for the putty session to login into server A. This works fine. now I want to access a service running on port 8443 from the browser on my local host. I have tried to create a ssh tunnel in putty using source port as 8443 ad destination as 8443:localhost:8443 but it doesn't work. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `ServerA` you have to create a tunnel to `ServerB`, or it will not work. The remote command on `ServerA` must be something like this:

```
ssh -L:8443:ServerB:8443
```

Later you create the tunnel on PuTTY, using `8443` as the source, and `localhost:8443` as the destination.

Comment: Thanks @thoriumBR for the answer. The solution worked for me. However I have added the ssh tunnel command in the putty session for `ServerA` to login directly into `ServerB`. Then I have added a tunnel in putty using `8443` as source and `localhost:8443` as the destination. I am able to access the service running on port `8443` on `ServerB` from my browser.